# How do you leave a game in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I need help to leave a Dota 2 game.

Someone left and never came back and therefore everyone left except me. It also says its safe to leave the game?

How can I leave a Dota 2 game?

Comment: but be in mind..if you are playing rank match then don't leave game even all your player left or else you will get lp and mmr will be decrease..but in condition of poor network detected and safe to leave, follow klm123's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find menu/search_for_game screen button at the top left. When you go there you will see leave button at the place where you have search panel usually - at the middle of the screen.

Comment: It's also worth noting, some rare time the UI is buggy and the button won't respond, you can force it by typing "disconnect" in the console.

Comment: In 2020, the button for the main menu is at the top left, displayed as the DotA logo. In the main menu, the leave game button is at the lower right. In case the button is missing, you may use the console to set `force_leave_game_button 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Click the top left arrow icon to open the main menu, then click the **Disconnect** button in the middle of the screen or at the bottom right of the screen (in Dota 2 Reborn).

If you also want to abandon the game and search for a new one, press **Leave Game** (under Reconnect) after you disconnected.